# Google Sheets - Can not write an OR statement inside of an AND statement

Tags: excel, if-statement, formula

I am using the below formula:

```
=IF(AND(F71="Meal",J71="No",L71="",I71<=AR71,(OR(L71="No",L71="no")),I71,""))
```

Breakdown:

```
IF 
F71=Meal 
AND J71=No 
AND L71=""
AND I71<=AR71
AND (L71="No" OR L71="no")
THEN
I71
ELSE
""
```

The error I receive is:
"Wrong number of arguments to IF. Expected between 2 and 3 arguments, but received 1 arguments."

Can someone please help guide me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Please! try this formula. You need to put an extra closing bracket.

```
 =IF(AND(F71="Meal",J71="No",L71="",I71<=AR71,(OR(L71="No",L71="no"))),I71,"")
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks Attiq. Sadly I get the error "Wrong number of arguments to IF. Expected between 2 and 3 arguments, but received 1 arguments." I use the formula: =IF(AND(F71="Airport Transfer",J71="No",L71="",I71<=AF71,(OR(L71="No",L71="no")),I71,
"NA"))